# How to save file when downloading in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, download

I am writing a multi-threaded downloader use csharp, but how to save data blocks of different threads.

My current approach is to save the data downloaded by each thread and merge them when the download is complete. But when doing this, the final merge may take a long time when dealing with large files.

Is there a way to allow different threads to write to the same file?

What are the best practices for writing files when downloading in multiple threads?

Comment: Why not write it all to one file? You can open the file in shared mode, seek to the part of the file to which the block belongs, and write to there.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Thanks, I solved the problem using FileShare.Write

Comment: Did you get any performance improvements by using multithreading?

Comment: Multi-threaded downloading under the condition of server speed limit, the download speed is significantly improved